# Highcharts throwing container not found error but the container exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, highcharts

I'm just wiring up high charts to use with my application and I'm using: **knockout 3.0**, **require.js 2.1**, **bootstrap 3.0**, **jquery 2.1** in it. I have wired in high charts in my require.config file like this:

```
requirejs.config(
    baseUrl: 'thirdparty',
    packages: [
         ......
        {name: 'Highcharts', location: 'highcharts', main: 'highcharts.js'}
    ],
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery/jquery',
        'highcharts': 'highcharts/highcharts.exporting.module',
        'highcharts-theme': 'highcharts/dark-blue',
        'highcharts-module': 'highcharts/highcharts'
    },
    shim: {
        'highcharts-module': {exports: 'Highcharts', deps: ['jquery']},
        'highcharts-theme': ['highcharts-module'],
        'highcharts': {deps: ['highcharts-module', 'highcharts-theme'], exports: 'Highcharts'}
    }
);
```

This is my knockout view model:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'Highcharts'], function($, ko){
    return function MyViewModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.chartOptions = {.....}  // copy pasted stuff from one of the examples
        self.drawChart = function(){
            #("#container").highchart(self.chartOptions);
        }
        self.drawChart();
    }
});
```

**ko.applyBinds** is done in this vm's parent. This is my html template, its prettymuch a container with a div inside:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="well container">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I reload the browser, I get this error:

** Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 **
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at self.drawChart()? It could be that the container is not actually present when drawChart is called. A JSFiddle would help immensely in diagnosing your issue!

Comment: You were right! The div wasn't getting loaded when the vm's code was running. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay thanks to Esteban's suggestion, I was able to figure out why the div wasn't being loaded when the vm's code was running. I fixed it by adding a custom binding handler to knockout.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.initHighCharts ={
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if(val.data){
                try {
                    $(element).highcharts(val.data);
                } catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        }
    };
```

And did this in the html template:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 no-margin">
    <div class="well container">
        <div data-bind="initHighCharts: {data: chartingOptions}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The custom binding makes the vm's code to fire after the div is loaded.